# Cursor position after pasting

Tags: cut-copy-paste, cursor

I believe the default behaviour in vi(m) for pasting (`p`) or (`P`) was to leave the cursor at the current position as before pasting, and in order to paste a register and have the cursor be at the end of the pasted text one would need to use the commands `gp` and `gP` respectively. I get only the latter behaviour, but I would like to have the former, what configuration options do I have to change for that?

Comment: Possible duplicate to stackoverflow: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1587178/paste-in-vim-without-moving-the-cursor. Afaik from https://vi.meta.stackexchange.com/questions/45/what-do-we-do-with-questions-that-are-already-answered-somewhere-else-on-se this question should not be closed and get a new and better answer here. However, I do not know what better would be for this question and therefore I leave this to someone else.

Comment: My understanding: `p` and `P` leave the cursor on the last character of the pasted text. If lines are pasted, the cursor is on the first non-blank of the first of the pasted lines. Vim behaves like that and a [descendant of the original Vi](http://ex-vi.sourceforge.net) also.